# Why doesn't this battery voltage measurement circuit work?

Tags: arduino, transistors, batteries, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

So, I built this simple circuit for measuring voltage from a battery pack to an Arduino.

The thing is, I want to measure the first cell and then the voltage from the whole battery pack: using two transistors for changing the voltage divider input (check the image so that you know what I mean.)

I do not want to apply a constant load to the battery, that's why I'm using transistors to turn on and off the voltage divider circuit.

Here's the circuit:

[image: Simple circuit for measuring the battery pack voltage]

I'm using a simple calculation when reading from pin A0: 0-1023 (analog range) reading to 0-25 volts (as the voltage divider is at a 5:1 ratio.)

My question isn't about the code. Here's the situation:

When both transistors are off, I get a 0 Volts reading (as it should).

When the first transistor is on, and the second is off, I get a ~4.2v reading (as it should.)

The problem is when the second transistor is on (and the first is off). I get the SAME reading (~4.2v) instead of 8.4v (the whole battery pack voltage.)

Adding diodes between each collector and the voltage divider for protection didn't alter my results.

I'm really confused about this.

UPDATE
Note: Each battery cell is rated at 4.2v.

Real Schematic:

[image: Real Schematic]

Comment: Please add a schematic. A wiring diagram doesn't count and is nigh-impossible to understand. That said, you seem to be using BJTs for this. BJTs are not suited for this use due to their saturation voltage.

Comment: Also... can the arduino survive 18V input? even if it can survive it why are you using it? It doesn't need more than a little above 5V, say 7V.

Comment: It's not 18v, i know in the image i'm using 9v batteries but in reality it's a Li-po battery pack. (As i said above the 9v batteries).

Comment: Is there any way i can make that circuit work? Maybe changing those bjts for power transistors like a MOSFET?

Comment: What you want to do can be done with MOSFET's. But you have to post a real schematic so we can figure out what you actually did without looking up everything, including whether BC548 is NPN or PNP, etc. Then someone should be able to suggest a minimal change that will work. You might also try googling this. It is a common problem, how to use a divider to sample a high voltage but disable the divider when you don't want to load the voltage. Usually I use an NMOS to switch the gate of a PMOS which is pulled up to the high voltage (battery or whatever).

Comment: Schematic. We need to see a real schematic.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than a wiring diagram. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. Use the Custom Component for the microcontroller.

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: UPDATE: Schematic added!

Comment: @John: On StackExchange you don't need to modify your post title to indicate that it is solved. When you accept an answer your question will show up on the main index with a green background on the number of answers box. I'll remove the "[FINISHED]" for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a **low-side** switch configuration in a **high-side** switch application. You can keep most of what you have if you just change to a **high-side** switch using PNP instead of NPN transistors. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1vU7l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help Heath! I really appreciated it!

Comment: At first glance I think this will work. But if good accuracy is required, Q1 and Q2 could be replaced with MOSFET's to avoid the collector-emitter drop. And those diodes will drop voltage, too. It might be best to reconsider a few parts of the circuit unless great accuracy is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the emitter voltage on the transistor can't go higher than the base voltage.

You're measuring the base voltage, minus two diode drops, not the collector voltage.

You could try using an "analog switch" or "analog mux" IC instead of a single transistor.  Pay attention to the allowed voltage range for the signal pins.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Circuit from OP.*

This won't work. Your transistors are wired as voltage followers. The emitter voltages will be about 0.7 V below the base voltage. This is confirmed by

> When the first transistor is on, and the second is off, i get a ~4.2v reading (as it should.) The problem is when the second transistor is on (and the first is off). I get the SAME reading (~4.2v) instead of 8.4v (the whole bpack voltage).

The emitter of either transistor can't go above about 4.3 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEQuv3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A simple solution using two analog inputs.*

This will reduce the voltage by a factor of two on each measurement input.

Comment: "I do not want to apply a constant load to the battery, that's why i'm using transistors to turn on and off the voltage divider circuit."

Comment: OK, but do you understand now why your circuit doesn't work (which is the title of your question)?

Comment: Thanks, @Ben. It's also helpful if I don't try to respond to comments using my phone just before I fall asleep in bed!